# Using sequences to show that limits of certain functions as certain values are approached do not exist

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I vaguely recall from undergraduate analysis that there is a relationship that allows
sequences to be used to show that certain limits don't exist. For example, I recently
came across a limit problem, specifically the limit of $\sin(1/x)$ as $x$ approaches zero.
The person who posted the solution used sequences to show that this limit does not exist.
I was wondering if someone would be kind enough to refresh my memory and generalize this
process along with any theorems that may be necessary or perhaps refer me to another internet resource that would do so, as I was
foolish enough to sell my analysis text, and I don't believe a basic undergraduate calculus text would cover this topic.

Thanks

Comment: F(x) converges to as x goes to x0 iff for every sequence yn going x0, F(yn) converges to a unique limit

Comment: Use wikipedia for "limit of a function" and "continuity". I'm not sure that the wikipedia article on "singularity" is readable enough, but in general the exceptions to continuity are treated under this heading "singularities of real functions". The concrete example is discussed under "Topologist's sine curve".

Answer (score -1):

For any fixed $a\in[-1,1]$, the equation $f(x)=\sin(1/x)=a$ has infinitely many solutions on every interval $(0,\delta)$, from which you can construct a sequence $x_n\to 0$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n)=a$. Since you can reach any $a\in[-1,1]$, the limit as a function does not exist. This applies to any oscillating singularity.

Comment: @Did, care to explain?

Comment: Sure. Read the question.

Comment: Then read again my answer and how it explains how to construct such sequences.

Comment: My first comment was deleted (I wonder why), so here it is again: "Off-topic." To belabor the obvious, the OP's query is not about the function $f:x\mapsto\sin(1/x)$ per se (whose case they seem to know) but about the more general setting explicitely described in the title (and in the text). Thus, Lost1's comment seems fully on-topic.

Comment: The point that Dud skipped over is that the graph of sin(1/x) does not only have two points (as it is usually demonstrated) as accumulation points, but the whole segment [-1,1]. Which makes it different from a jump discontinuity.

Comment: "Skipped over"? I find telling that, just as you are unable to read the question, you are unable to write correctly my username. (In the future, please use @ to signal your comments.)